# Command To Remove Just Deeper Level Headlines From The ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

When using `*`in a headline you remove the section from the toc. But sometimes you just want to remove a certain level of headlines. Rather than to remove every single headline individually, it would be more pleasant to change one superordinate headline to serve that purpose.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a `*`-based command that removes deeper level headlines without removing the level to where it is applied.

For example:

```
\section*{asdf}
\subsection{fdsa}
\section{B}
\subsection{C}
```

The asdf-headline will be displayed in the toc while the subsection will be removed. Both, section B and section C are part of the toc either.

Ideally, the command would not redefine the `\section*{`but would offer an alternative to allow being used at the same time as with an other command that was recently defined ([Removing Subordinated Headline Levels From The ToC Automatically When Using `*`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65220/removing-subordinated-headline-levels-from-the-toc-automatically-when-using)).

Comment: This question is a little unclear.  What do you hope to achieve that the `tocvsec2` package doesn't already do? See especially the `\maxtocdepth` and `\settocdepth` commands, which should be used after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I am also curious about this sentence: 'Both, section B and section C are part of the toc either.'  It almost seems to be missing a 'not' (i.e., 'are not part of the toc either'), which is a very different question!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this does what you need (based on your code snippet):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\begin{document}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\section*{asdf}                         
\subsection{fdsa}

\settocdepth{chapter} % <-- comment this line to see the difference
\chapter{A} 
\section{B} 
\subsection{C}

\settocdepth{subsection}   
\chapter{D} 
\section{E}  
\subsection{F}  

\end{document}
```

(Remember to compile twice to see how things change in the table of contents.)